# Matlab creating a mask

Tags: arrays, matlab, masking

1. How to use mod() to create a mask of where A contains an even number?
   C =
2. How to replace values with a mask. Using your mask, C, assign the even values in var1 into the corresponding values of var2.
   D =
3. Use 'and' and 'or' to find a mask of where both A and C were true. 
   E =

Thank You.

Comment: Perhaps you could show what you've tried and specific problem your having.

Comment: It's not my homework. I just wanna learn how to use it. The questions are on the book.

Comment: So what have you learnt? Or is it a book full of questions only? If so, they must be publishing a follow-up book with the solutions soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is all very basic MATLAB.

(1)

```
A = [7 8 10 11 13 18];

C = mod(A, 2)==0;

A(find(C))
```

(2)

```
var1 = zeros(20,1);
var2 = A;
var1(find(C)) = var2(find(C));
```

(3)

```
C = (mod(A,2)==0);
D = (mod(A,3)==0);

A(find(C|D))

A(find(C&D))
```